# swing application issue in authentication using javax.mail.authenticator

Tags: java, swing

I am developing an swing application for sending the mail using authentication.
The Issue I am facing is when i enter wrong username and password it is giving AuthenticationException after that when i enter correct userid and password  again it is giving same exception. if i close whole application and start again and enter correct uid and password than it is working perfectly.

what i wanted is when it throw the AuthenticationException i want to show the message to user and allow them to change the password and user id without restarting whole application again

I am trying it from last 3 days without success please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a sub-class of `Authenticator` and override the `getPasswordAuthentication()`. Read this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html) and [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those links.I resolved the issue. Before i was using Transport.send() static method that's why i was not able to close the connection now i am using specific instance for Transport class and closing the connection using transport.close().